# Constructing hex data payload for contract interaction

Tags: metamask, calldata, hex, function-selector

I am trying to construct the data payload as described here and quoted below for interacting with a contract:
https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#transmitting-a-data-payload-to-an-eoa-or-contract

Can someone please explain what it means to "add the function selector to the amount"?

I see that the 2 shorter hex values need to maybe be added (or concatenated) with 0's, but the number of zeros seem very high in the example result below, even if you pad each separately.

What am I missing about the adding or padding process?

I realize there are libraries to help with this, but I am trying to understand the construction process.

Thanks in advance.

> Let’s calculate the Keccak-256 hash of this string:
>
> > web3.utils.sha3("withdraw(uint256)"); '0x2e1a7d4d13322e7b96f9a57413e1525c250fb7a9021cf91d1540d5b69f16a49f'
> > The first 4 bytes of the hash are 0x2e1a7d4d. That’s our "function
> > selector" value, which will tell the contract which function we want
> > to call.
>
> Next, let’s calculate a value to pass as the argument withdraw_amount.
> We want to withdraw 0.01 ether. Let’s encode that to a hex-serialized
> big-endian unsigned 256-bit integer, denominated in wei:
>
> > withdraw_amount = web3.utils.toWei(0.01, "ether"); '10000000000000000'
> > withdraw_amount_hex = web3.utils.toHex(withdraw_amount); '0x2386f26fc10000' Now, we **add the function selector to the amount**
> > (padded to 32 bytes):
>
> 2e1a7d4d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000

Comment: What is the exact question? You have the 4 bytes of the function selector (2e1a7d4d) + 32 bytes padded data (000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002386f26fc10000), which is 64 hex values.

Comment: I do not understand how 32 bytes of padded data equates to that, other than that you mention that it needs to be 64 hex values, which is somewhat of a clarification. So am I correct that "adding" in this context is just concatenating the function selector with the other data, padded to 64 hex values?

Comment: 1 byte = 8 bits = 2^8 = 16^2 = 2 hex values if that helps. Yes, you're right, "adding" is just concatenating.